# Compare values Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I need to extract **Kb/s** column values from  data from below.

```
read:             ops/s            Kb/s           Kb/op         retrans         avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                 11.888         919.508          77.347       -2 (-0.0%)          3.486           3.607
```

I am trying to print awk '{print$3}', but it printing column name as Kb/s but printing value from Kb/op .

```
Kb/s
77.340
```

Can you please advice how i can grep required value.i.e Kb/s=919.452

-Thanks.

Comment: How are the columns separated? Are they tab-separated or is that all white-space? If they are tab-separated, you can use a field separator in your expression `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } ; { print $3 }'` although the exact form of the tab separator might depend on your OS.

Comment: `read:`  is taken as an extra field, so you have a 1 field offset, easy workaround is removing it with sed or awk.

Comment: @xvan : Can you please explain , How to do that ?. Thanks

Comment: `sed 's/^read://'`

Comment: Do you want the `Kb/s` column heading as well as the value?  What other lines are there in the input — are they before the lines shown, or after them, or both?  Should any of those be handled too?  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your header has one extra column compare to the data set. Try:

```
awk '$2 ~/^[0-9]+/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks , that worked.Can you please explain what that command do?

Comment: Looks for the 2nd field which starts with one or more numeric values -- so this will skip the header.

Comment: below code is failing, array is not passing values to the if condition.  
`echo "rops is ${rops[*]}"  
for i in ${rops[*]}  
do  
if [[ "${rops[i]}" == 4000 ]]; then  
echo "issue there"  
fi  
done  `

Comment: @Vijay If adesilva solved your problem, you should "accept" his answer by clicking on the check mark to the left.This helps future readers with the same question and it also saves time for those of us who look
for _unanswered_ questions.  For more information on Stackoverflow's
peculiar customs, see: [What should I do when someone answers my
question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can "fix" the input like @xvan commented:

```
sed 's/^read//' inputfile | awk '{print $2}'
```

or instruct awk to choose the correct field:

```
awk '{print ($1=="read:")? $3 : $2}' inputfile
```